# Please explain two syntaxes for IIFE

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference between: `(function () {})()`, and `(function () {}())`?

I've seen both constructs referenced, and would like to know if they represent two equivalent ways of constructing the exact same expression, or are they two different expressions/constructs altogether? If different, how are they different?

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate.  This has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) and [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23925102) already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These expressions are equivalent.
A closure is created, then called. The value of the expression is the closure's return value.

The simplest form would be `function () {}()`, however at the top level, where an IIFE would be used, that is a SyntaxError. Therefore either the creation of the closure, or the whole expression is parenthesized. 
However it would work in an expression context, for example

```js
let a = function () {}()
```

*Update*: A third form you'll sometimes see, for example in minified JS is `!function () {}()`, of course the return value is different in this case.